# Where can I share my guitar arrangements to get more youtube traffic?

Tags: performing, arranging, publishing

Do you know of any sites where people would be interested in video game OST guitar arrangements?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off-site resource requests including where to post music is off-topic.